# How to retrieve records from a specific table using the ActiveRecord has_many through association in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using the has_many :through association example from the RailsGuide, how do you select all patients or physicians without appointments using ActiveRecord?

---

**2.4 The has_many :through Association**
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_many :enrollments
    has_many :courses, through: :enrollments

end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
    belongs_to :user

    scope :registered, -> { where("enrolled = ?", true) }
    scope :student, -> (student_id) { where("user_id = ?", student_id) }
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :update_slug

    has_many :enrollments
    has_many :users, through: :enrollments

    def update_slug
        self.slug = title.parameterize
    end

    def to_param
        slug
    end

    # scope :available, -> { where.not(id: Enrollment.pluck(:course_id)).uniq }
    scope :available, -> (student_id) { where.not(id: Enrollment.pluck(:course_id)).uniq }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* thing you can do is to first select all the IDs from the join table/model, and then use the list to exclude records from the second query:

```
Physician.where.not(id: Appointment.pluck(:physician_id).uniq)
Patient.where.not(id: Appointment.pluck(:patient_id).uniq)
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. How could I filter the records based on which Patient is signed?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use pure SQL which i personally prefer:

```
Physician.where("
  not exists (select 1 from appointments 
  where appointments.physician_id = physician.id)
")

Patient("
  not exists (select 1 from appointments 
  where appointments.patient_id = patient.id)
")
```

As for "How could I filter the records based on which Patient is signed?", what exactly do you mean?

```
Appointment.find_by(patient_id: 123).patient
Appointment.find_by(patient_id: 123).physician
```

Comment: In my project the Patient is equivalent to User (using Devise gem), Physician is equivalent to Course and Appointment is equivalent to Enrollment. When I use Course.where.not(id: Enrollment.pluck(:course_id)).uniq from a User account (without a row in the Enrollment table) it hides the Course from another User (without a row in the Enrollment table).

Comment: I added my classes if it's helpful

Comment: I think this solution is superior to mine, as it will use only one query instead of two. Mine was meant to be the _simple and quick_ thing to do. This is better.

Comment: @Ray - You are talking right now about this "available" scope right? And it should return Courses that don't have any Enrollments, right? I would write it as `scope :available, -> { where("not exists(select 1 from enrollments e where e.course_id = courses.id)") }` .